# Is any method to loading kml in background in html with java script

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I trying to loading kml file on map in html but it takes more time to loading kml file on mobile screen 
and then show kml file on map after long time.I want to know is any method to load it in background like android I used below code to loading kml file.

```
var geoXml = null;
    var map = null;
    var myLatLng = null;
    var i;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), myOptions);

        geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
            map: map,
            singleInfoWindow: true
        });
        geoXml.parse('mykml.KML');

    });
```

Comment: Why are you using geoxml3? If you don't need access to the data in the KML file, use the native [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers), which renders the data as tiles.

Comment: @Geocodezip thanks for your suggestion but its not working for me.My code is:function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851)
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'mykml.KML'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: Is the KML publicly available?  Perhaps specify the absolute URL for the KML file.

Comment: I take KML file from my local directory.